# Solving $\log_2(e+\log_3(e+\log_4(e+...)))$

Tags: logarithms

I have been trying to find the exact value of $\log_2(e+\log_3(e+\log_4(e+...)))$. Using Desmos, I know it is approximately $1.95924$. I tried using WolframAlpha by using the Nest function but was unable to get it working properly because I am pretty new to WolframAlpha.

What I want to know is how I would solve it mathematically? I don't really know where to start so any help is appreciated.

Comment: Another pertinent question would be to ask whether it is defined at all

Comment: How would I determine whether or not it is?

Comment: @insipidintegrator It is bounded and increasing.

Comment: [Here](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=Fold%5Blog%28%232%2Ce%2B%231%29%26%2C+0.0%2C+Reverse%5BRange%5B2%2C10%5D%5D%5D) is your constant in Wolfram Alpha after consulting reference.wolfram.com  for commands in the link

Comment: Do you have any reason to believe that it will have a closed form?

Comment: I do not have any reason to believe it has a closed form

Comment: An alternate problem is $(\dots)^{4^{3^{2^x-e}-e}}-e=0$, but Wolfram Alpha [says](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=Fold%5Blog%28%232%2Ce%2B%231%29%26%2C+x%2C+Reverse%5BRange%5B2%2Cinfinity%5D%5D%5D) it is somehow $\frac 1{\ln(2)}$

Comment: The number is
$$1.95923767644389672726868190001030589416511942660786456645584\cdots$$ all digits being exact.

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici Confirmed 24 digs.

Answer (score 2):

If we know $\,a_n\,$ for certain $\,n \gg 1,$ then $a_{n-1}=y(a_n, n),\;$
wherein
$$y(x)=\dfrac{\ln(e+x)}{\ln(n)} = \dfrac{1+\ln(1+x/e)}{\ln(n)}
\approx \dfrac{{1+\dfrac xe-\dfrac{x^2}{2e^2}}}{{{\ln(n)}}}, \tag1 $$
Since denominators and numerators of $(1)$ changes slowly, then asymptotically $a_{n-1}\rightarrow a_n.$

Assuming $y= x$, easily to get [the table of the approximated and exact  estimations](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=Table%7BN%5B%28-e%20log%28n%29%20-%20ProductLog%28-1%2C%20-n%5E%28-e%29%20log%28n%29%29%29%2Flog%28n%29%2C%2012%5D%2C%20N%5Be%20%28sqrt%28e%5E2%20log%5E2%28n%29%20-%202%20e%20log%28n%29%20%2B%203%29%20-%20e%20log%28n%29%20%2B%201%29%2C%2012%5D%20%7D%2C%20%7Bn%2C%202%2C%2020%7D)
$$a_{n}\approx 
a_{n-1}\approx x\approx y\approx e\sqrt{e^2\ln^2 n - 2e \ln n+3} - e\ln n -1)\tag2$$
[Exact solution](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=solve%20ln%28e%2B%20x%29%3D%20x%20ln%2011%20over%20positive%20reals) has the closed form via analytic continuation of the Lambert W-function and has not essential differences from $(2).$

[image: Starting points]
[image: Iterations from 20 to 11]
[image: Iterations from 11 to 2]

Iterations from the starting value $a_{20}$ ([Table1](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=a%28n%2B1%29%3Dln%28e%2Ba%28n%29%29%2Fln%2821-n%29%2C%20a%282%29%3D0.376881)) to $a_2$ ([Table2](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=a%28n%2B1%29%3Dln%28e%2Ba%28n%29%29%2Fln%2821-n%29%2C%20a%2811%29%3D0.482726)) are shown at the right columns (at the inverse order).

Wolfram Alpha suffices all described calculations.

Comment: What is the closed form of $1.959\dots$ then?

Comment: @TymaGaidash I did not solve this task

Comment: @TymaGaidash My calculations from $N=26$ with 40 digits give 1.959237676443896727268682687782609632598